# Starting Python program got some strings format issue

Tags: python

I'm a very new coding users, I wrote a small python script, but there is some format issue I can't solved, could you please give some advise?

```
   while(True):
        keyword = "edit clients are "
        p = buf.find(keyword)
        if(p == -1):
            break

        p = buf.find(keyword)
        usage_count = int(buf[:p].split())
        buf = buf[p+len(keyword):]
        print "================== %s usage_count" % usage_count


        ret.append(LicenseSitRep(usage_count))

    return ret
```

The output says:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

My search value is below, and my expect output should be 11.

```
Jun 14 11:01:58 license server: Current accepted edit clients are 11.
```

Comment: `buf[:p].split()` returns a list not a string.

Comment: I changed to buf[:p].split() to int(buf[:p]), then the output says:
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Jun 14 11:21:46 license server: Current accepted 
The output should be a number like "11"

Comment: Can you `print(buf[:p].split())` ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is from this line

```
usage_count = int(buf[:p].split())
```

The reason is the `split` function return a `list` not a `str`, you can change the code like that.

```
usage_count = int(buf[:p].split()[0])
```

**Edit:**

for to get the `11`, you can found from the debug process.

```
[in] buf = r"Jun 14 11:01:58 license server: Current accepted edit clients are 11."
[in] p = 49
[in] buf[p:]
[out] 'edit clients are 11.'
[in] buf[:p]
[out] 'Jun 14 11:01:58 license server: Current accepted '
[in] buf[p:].split(" ")
['edit', 'clients', 'are', '11.']
[in] buf[p:].split(" ")[-1]
[out] '11.'
[in] buf[p:].split(" ")[-1].split(".")
[out] ['11', '']
[in] buf[p:].split(" ")[-1].split(".")[0]
[out] '11'
```

you can try this code.

```
usage_count = int(buf[p:].split(" ")[-1].split(".")[0])
```

Comment: Thanks Saul, this comes another error after I changed the code like yours:

` usage_count = int(buf[:p].split()[0]) `

The error output is:

  `usage_count = int(buf[:p].split()[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Jun'`

Comment: It's working! update my code to `usage_count = int(buf[p:].split(" ")[-1].split(".")[0])` got the data what I want!

Really appreciate the detailed debug process, that's really helpful for me to lean how to debug if I have issue again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not take advantage of regex via re and just do this?

```
import re 
buf = "Jun 14 11:01:58 license server: Current accepted edit clients are 11."
# ...
p = buf.find(keyword)
buf = buf[p+len(keyword):]
buf = int(re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', buf))
usage_count = buf
```

Answer (score 0):

using a regex is much more feasible I guess

```
import re
buf = "Jun 14 11:01:58 license server: Current accepted edit clients are 11."
if bool(re.match(r'.*edit\sclients\sare\s\d+.$', buf)):
    usage_count = re.findall(r'edit\sclients\sare\s(\d+?)\.', buf)
    print "================== %s usage_count" % usage_count[0]
```